# c++ uwp project upgrade not re targeting WindowsDesktop Properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, uwp

I have a c++ UWP project that started with VS15 then upgraded to VS17 and now VS19.

After retargeting the solution I get errors:

MSB3774Could not find SDK "WindowsDesktop, Version=10.0.10240.0".

MSB3774Could not find SDK "WindowsDesktop, Version=10.0.10586.0"

Those versions are not in the properties page anywhere.

Comment: So I went to the vs17 installer and added the SDK versions above.  I got the following error:

ErrorC2371'ABI::Windows::Foundation::Numerics::Rational': redefinition; different basic types 

Does it appear that I'm using multiple SDK's? ??? 

How do I set the target SDK in VS?

Comment: I have tested with Visual Studio 2019. Unfortunately,I could not reproduce your issue. Could you mind share a min sample?

Comment: I opened the .vcxproj file and found the following entries:
    <SDKReference Include="WindowsDesktop, Version=10.0.10240.0" />
    <SDKReference Include="WindowsDesktop, Version=10.0.10586.0" />
Is in many years of developemnt, I have never edited this file.  Is there a way to have it automatically regenerated?

Comment: I commented out the lines above and got the redefination error again.  The 10586 is referenced in another part of the document.  Although its now not available for loading.

Comment: Have you tried to modify the target and mini version to another ?